# How to program a "get field" function in Java for our game board in Peg-Solitaire

Tags: java

```
public class SolitaireBoard {

    private static final int empty = 0;
    private static final int occupied = 1;
    private static final int invalid = 2;
    public int col;
    public int row;
    public SolitaireBoard(){
        int [] [] board = {
            {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
            {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
            {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
            {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
            {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
        };
    }
}
```

I need to programm a get field function that has row and col (column) as an input and returns the state of the specific field. I was not able to find any solution online.

Comment: What does `row` and `col` attributs represent ? The class should have a `board` attribut in fact

Comment: row and col should be like the x and y coordinate. I'm an absolute beginner, so there is no guarantee that this code is usable at all. For example get field(0, 4) should return "occupied"

Answer (score 0):

It seems your class should not have `row,col` attributs, but a `board` one, like

```
public class SolitaireBoard {
    private static final int empty = 0;
    private static final int occupied = 1;
    private static final int invalid = 2;
    private int[][] board;
    public SolitaireBoard(){
        this.board = new int[][]{
            {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}, // Should be {invalid, invalid, invalid, occupied, ...}
            {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Then build a method to access a box

```
public int getField(int row, int col){
    return this.board[row][col];
}
```

---

To manipulate more easily your constants, you could reduce their name, like `EM, OC, IN` and build the array with them

```
new int[][]{
    {IN, IN, IN, OC, OC, OC, IN, IN, IN},
    {IN, IN, IN, OC, OC, OC, IN, IN, IN},
    {IN, IN, IN, OC, OC, OC, IN, IN, IN},
    {OC, OC, OC, OC, OC, OC, OC, OC, OC},
    {OC, OC, OC, OC, EM, OC, OC, OC, OC},
    {OC, OC, OC, OC, OC, OC, OC, OC, OC},
    {IN, IN, IN, OC, OC, OC, IN, IN, IN},
    {IN, IN, IN, OC, OC, OC, IN, IN, IN},
    {IN, IN, IN, OC, OC, OC, IN, IN, IN},
};
```

Comment: This gives me an error with "array initializer is not allowed here"     EDIT: didn't see the rest of your post

Answer (score 0):

You have to make board a property, so you can get a specific field from another method. If you want to access a field you have to count from zero. For example if you want to access a field from the first row, you have to type in the index 0 for the row.

```
public class SolitaireBoard {

    private static final int empty = 0;
    private static final int occupied = 1;
    private static final int invalid = 2;
    public int[][] board;
    public int col;
    public int row;

    public SolitaireBoard(){
        board = new int[][]{
                {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
                {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
                {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
                {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
                {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2},
        };
    }

    public int getField(int row, int column) {
        return board[row][column];
    }
}
```